# Can't import custom font using @font-face in stripe elements

Tags: css, stripe-payments, clojurescript

I cannot use my custom font with stripe elements for some reason:

```
// Case 1
stripe.elements (fonts: {
    family: "Indie Flower"
    src: "url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/indieflower/v11/m8JVjfNVeKWVnh3QMuKkFcZVaUuH99GUDg.woff2)"
    weight: 500
})


// Case 2
stripe.elements (fonts: {
    family: "Gotham-Light"
    src: "url(http://localhost:5000/my-font)"
    weight: 500
})
```

When I use Indie Flower as the font using, fontFamily: "Indie Flower", I see the font in the stripe element, but not with "Gotham-Light".

Here's the actual clojurescript code:

```
(let [
          elements (.elements stripe
                              (clj->js
                               ;; {:fonts [{:family "Gotham-Light"
                               ;;           :src (str "url(" (url) "/gotham-light" ")")
                               ;;           :weight 500
                               ;;           }]}
                               {:fonts [{:family "Indie Flower"
                                         :src (str "url(" (url) "/indie)")
                                         ;;:src "url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/indieflower/v11/m8JVjfNVeKWVnh3QMuKkFcZVaUuH99GUDg.woff2)"
                                         :weight 500
                                         }]}
                               )
                              )
          card-element
          (.create elements "card"
                   (clj->js
                    {:style
                     {:base
                      {
                       :fontFamily "Indie Flower, Helvetica, sans-serif"
                       :fontSize 16
                       }
                      :invalid
                      {:color "#FFC7EE"}
                      }
                     }
                    ))]

      (.mount card-element "#card-element")
      (assoc db :stripe stripe :card-element card-element)
      )
```

Server side is this:
Server side is this:
Server side is this:
Server side is this:

```
(defn font-handler2 [req]
  (assoc (resource-response "indie.woff2" {:root "public/"})
         :headers {
                   "Age" "608650",
                   "Content-Type" "font/woff2",
                   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*",
                   "Timing-Allow-Origin" "*",
                   "X-Content-Type-Options" "nosniff",
                   "Content-Length" "19120",
                   "Alt-Svc"
                   "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\",h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000",
                   "Connection" "close",
                   "Accept-Ranges" "bytes",
                   "X-XSS-Protection" "0",
                   "Cache-Control" "public, max-age=31536000"})


  )



(def routes ["/indie" font-handler2])
```

If it helps, here are the responses without the body (which is really long, but it's the same in both cases, which I have in fact checked.)

```
user> (dissoc (http/get "http://localhost:5000/indie") :body)
{:cached nil,
 :request-time 7,
 :repeatable? false,
 :protocol-version {:name "HTTP", :major 1, :minor 1},
 :streaming? true,
 :http-client
 #object[org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient 0x1947efde "org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient@1947efde"],
 :chunked? false,
 :reason-phrase "OK",
 :headers
 {"Content-Type" "font/woff2",
  "Server" "Aleph/0.4.4",
  "Connection" "Close",
  "Date" "Tue, 07 Apr 2020 16:40:53 GMT",
  "content-length" "19120"},
 :orig-content-encoding nil,
 :status 200,
 :length 19120,
 :trace-redirects []}
user> (dissoc (http/get "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/indieflower/v11/m8JVjfNVeKWVnh3QMuKkFcZVaUuH99GUDg.woff2") :body)
{:cached nil,
 :request-time 47,
 :repeatable? false,
 :protocol-version {:name "HTTP", :major 1, :minor 1},
 :streaming? true,
 :http-client
 #object[org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient 0x4346f38b "org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient@4346f38b"],
 :chunked? false,
 :reason-phrase "OK",
 :headers
 {"Server" "sffe",
  "Age" "608650",
  "Content-Type" "font/woff2",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*",
  "Timing-Allow-Origin" "*",
  "X-Content-Type-Options" "nosniff",
  "Content-Length" "19120",
  "Alt-Svc"
  "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\",h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000",
  "Connection" "close",
  "Accept-Ranges" "bytes",
  "Expires" "Wed, 31 Mar 2021 15:37:07 GMT",
  "Date" "Tue, 31 Mar 2020 15:37:07 GMT",
  "Last-Modified" "Tue, 16 Jul 2019 23:56:42 GMT",
  "X-XSS-Protection" "0",
  "Cache-Control" "public, max-age=31536000"},
 :orig-content-encoding nil,
 :status 200,
 :length 19120,
 :trace-redirects []}
```

The first /indie is before I added the cors headers.

Comment: It's a little tough to answer this without the full context, like what the 'my-font' file is. Also this looks like pseudo-code, that isn't valid syntax for stripe.js(`fonts` is an array for example). Are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Yes, it is pseudocode, because I wanted to expand the number of people who can answer this question, since I'm using clojurescript, which many people might not be familiar with,. My edit will contain the actual code. I think it might have an issue with cors. Because when I download the google font and serve it through localhost, it doesn't work. But it still didn't work after adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the response.

Comment: Hmm, if it's a CORS problem that should be readily apparent from an error in the browser console. Whenever I've done local work with fonts like this in Stripe, I've needed to configure my server to allow the appropriate origin. https://enable-cors.org/

Comment: I don't really see any cors error. It was a guess because the difference between the google response and the localhost response was the absence of the cors headers in the latter, but even adding those didn't change much.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, here's an example I put together that uses it : https://lightning-antique-dawn.glitch.me/

Frontend code : https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lightning-antique-dawn?path=views/checkout.hbs:21:16

You'll note I had to set up CORS on the server : https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lightning-antique-dawn?path=server.js:12:53

That's because the actual Element is an iframe on Stripe's servers that loads your configuration, so you need to be able to support the js.stripe.com domain origin accessing the font file.

```
var elements = stripe.elements ({fonts: [{
    family: "Gotham Light",
    src: "url(/GothamLightRegular.otf)",
    weight: 500
}]})
var cardElement = elements.create('card', {
  style: {
    base: {
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontFamily: '"Gotham Light", sans-serif',
      fontSize: '15px',
    },
  }
});
cardElement.mount('#card-element');
```

Express backend configuration :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://js.stripe.com"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(express.static('public')); // contains the font file
```

Comment: These are the new headers I'm receiving:
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers"
  "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
  "Server" "Aleph/0.4.4",
  "Content-Type" "font/woff2",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "https://js.stripe.com",
  "Timing-Allow-Origin" "*",
  "X-Content-Type-Options" "nosniff",
  "content-length" "19120",
  "Connection" "Close",
  "Date" "Tue, 07 Apr 2020 23:25:23 GMT",
  "X-XSS-Protection" "0",
  "Cache-Control" "public, max-age=31536000"

Doesn't work.

Comment: Can you expand on what "Doesn't work" means? There's either come kind of warning/error in your browser console, or some issue with the specific font file, it's hard to say without seeing the site itself.

Comment: seems like a stripe bug because upon close inspection, the font does show up but it's way out of the scope of the text input. You see the bottom fringes of the text in the text input, but it's the correct font!

Answer (score 0):

Your example has a missing `{}`, so I presume the correct code would be:

```js
stripe.elements ({ fonts: {
    family: "Indie Flower"
    src: "url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/indieflower/v11/m8JVjfNVeKWVnh3QMuKkFcZVaUuH99GUDg.woff2)"
    weight: 500
}})
```

but in your Clojure example you are wrapping the fonts value in an extra vector. So you are effectively calling

```js
stripe.elements ({ fonts: [{
    family: "Indie Flower"
    src: "url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/indieflower/v11/m8JVjfNVeKWVnh3QMuKkFcZVaUuH99GUDg.woff2)"
    weight: 500
}]})
```

Note the extra array. I don't know anything about stripe but you may just need to remove the extra wrapping vector?

```clj
(.elements stripe
  (clj->js
    {:fonts
     {:family "Indie Flower"
      :src "url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/indieflower/v11/m8JVjfNVeKWVnh3QMuKkFcZVaUuH99GUDg.woff2)"
      :weight 500}}))
```

Comment: That's incorrect because removing the vector doesn't make even the font work through google url, which is already working.